# How to schedule execute a part of script in perl once every hour while the rest is refreshing every minute

Tags: javascript, perl

I have a Perl script that refreshes the web page every minute. Now I want to add some MySQL queries that should once every hour. Is there a schedule executor in Perl like in JavaScript or can I incorporate JavaScript in Perl?

Comment: Is it the perl script that actually refreshing the web page, or do the perl-script generate a web page that has a <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> (or similar javascript code)?

If meta/javascript refresh, you probably need to add a timestamp to the web-page as a cgi param (...&lastSqlRun=14:32) , and test if time has passed.

Comment: Perl script generates the web page and that has <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something like this. Include a timestamp that is carried forward to next update (adjust the meta-tag so that occurs). Some issues if sql must be run at exactly 1 hrs, but I guess it it just some maintenance. The timestamp is only updated if the sql is run, and the sql is only run if the current time is more than one hour after the previous timestamp.

The following updates the timestamp with 3600 seconds instead of using the current time. Then we are very close to running it every hour.

Some web developers don't like using meta refresh in this way, so javascript or cookie may be an option. (but if this works for you, be happy :- )

```
use strict;
use CGI;

#time() is number of seconds since long time ago
my $lastrun = CGI->param('lastrun') || time();

#if hour is important (ie not 58 or 61 minutes) then need to 
#consider the time spent running this script, etc
if (time() > $lastrun + 60 * 60) { #one hr is 60 sec * 60 min
    $lastrun += 60 * 60; #udate timestamp before starting sql
    #run sql
}

#do fixed stuff every minute

print qq|
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Type: text/html

    <html><head>
        <!-- remember to adust the url below ---vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-----here -- so time is ok vvvvv -->
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;URL='http://example.com/script.pl?lastrun=$lastrun">
    </head>
    <body>hello again, waiting...</body>    
    <html>
|;
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is with **Perl**.

You can use `localtime()` function in perl. 
Calculate the difference of an Hour and shoot MySQL queries.

To understand `localtime()` please visit [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) link.

**OR**

You can use CPAN's `Time::HiRes`.

Please read about `Time::HiRes` [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html).

**OR**

Follow this code:

```
use Time::Elapse;

## somewhere in your code...
Time::Elapse->lapse(my $now);

#...rest of code execution    
print "Time Elapsed: $now\n";
```